# Tooltip поверх таблицы

Tags: css, datatable

Всем привет!

Использую плагин tipr для тултипа. Вставляю в таблицу, но всплывающее окно обрезается таблицей от DataTable. Скриншот: http://prntscr.com/e5m4qx
Какое свойство нужно прописать для тултипа, чтобы он был поверх таблицы? Текущее значение:

```css
    .tipr_content
{
     font: 13px/1.7 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
     color: #333; 
     background-color: #fff;
     padding: 9px 17px;
 z-index: 999999;
}
.tipr_container_top
{
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     margin-top: -77px;
     box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #f9f9f9;
     z-index: 1000;
}
```

Буду рад и благодарен любой помощи или направлению!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте overflow: visible; для таблицы. Не для tooltip, а именно для таблицы.